# how to push to git from Terminal / Command Line

Tags: git, command-line, terminal

I added a file into the folder for Git uploading. I can see the folder in the SourceTree under unstaged. How can I push the file to online storage with terminal commands?

I figured it out I need to first cd to the local repository, which I did with this:

```
cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/Projects
git add -A .
```

checked status with `git status` and it outputs this:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   ios_projects/2016/Untitled copy 2.rtf // this is the file I want to upload
```

What now? How do I commit it and push it online?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

next thing would be to commit using and then push to what ever branch you want to push

```
git commit -m 'Some message about the change'

git push origin 'branch-name'
```

Comment: Thats great! Do you perhaps know how to commit current date and time as commit message?

Comment: hmm not really, you can surely manually add date and time to the commit message. I do know that you will surely see the commit date in your commit log or when you go to git commit tab. Hope that helps

Answer (score 17):

Turns out it is that simple:

```
cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/YourFolder
git add -A .
git commit -m 'commit message from terminal'
git push
```

Edit: if you use just `git commit` without `-m`, you will enter some editor to type commit message, which I don't know how to quit.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following cmd:

```
$ git status
$ git add <file_name>
$ git commit -m "<msg>"
$ git push origin <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter Your Terminal and Write Below Commands

```
git commit -m "Enter What should you Save as a Description"
```

And You Should push or commit with the Visual Studio code Editor also
Just go in and left side Source Control menu either press it ctrl+Shift+g and Commit or push after init Repository.